# SortedDictionary 's Extension Method OrderByDescending is Not Available for Web Pages ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I am trying to Sort the Items by Value in the `SortedDictionary`..

I had done that by `mySortedDictionary.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value);` it Returns the Sorted Key Value Pairs..

But in the same way I am using the `OrderByDescending` Method in ASP.NET web Page, But is says

> System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How could I achieve this operation in my web page?

any alternative technique???

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` is an extension method inside of `System.Linq`.

Make sure you have the relevant using statemenet at the top of your class

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yea. Thanks a Lot.. I didn't came to know that the extension methods are stored in the Namespace `System.Linq`.. Thank you @jamie Dixon